# How to Write query as like as mysql select and where in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I find data by multiple data as like as sql,Like I need to grab something Between date range where deliveryman===man,marchent===marchent,productStatus===status,Suppose I havent manId now so my query will return only data belongs to date range and matched with other conditions like marchent, productStatus, if i dont pass anything my query will return all data between selected date range. Date range will be available always, Thank you.

```
[{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":0,"express":false,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff34e7f5dbbabb7b13828f4","orderid":"7dy3jl","description":"Laptop New Apple","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Masum","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a19f70d2bd4ee06fe9a0","name":"Era","phone":"345345345"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"Nikunjo2,Road3,House7","productStatus":"Delivered","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T17:21:03.426Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T17:14:43.100Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":0,"express":false,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff34b586eb76bad64501559","orderid":"xx1wfo89","description":"Smart TV","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"adsf","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a14f70d2bd4ee06fe99f","name":"Raj","phone":"34354354"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"asdf","productStatus":"in progress","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T17:07:36.351Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T18:44:27.695Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":0,"express":false,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff34b307dca39ab609f5d23","orderid":"xx1wfo","description":"asdfasdf","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"adsf","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a14f70d2bd4ee06fe99f","name":"Raj","phone":"34354354"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"asdf","productStatus":"Cancelled","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T17:06:56.656Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T17:14:57.078Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":0,"express":false,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff3453e41ef4d995d392002","orderid":"osa7mj","description":"Khata Colom","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Masum","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a14f70d2bd4ee06fe99f","name":"Raj","phone":"34354354"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"Mohakhali dhaka","productStatus":"Delivered","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T16:41:34.041Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T15:11:27.359Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":5000,"express":true,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff33dda15a2f69817cde3a8","orderid":"5iapq1","description":"Sauces","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Rezaul","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a1f71a92f4509749976f","name":"masum","phone":"34534543"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"tomorrow 10 pm","receiverAddress":"Nikunju-2,Road 3","productStatus":"on the way","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T16:10:02.029Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T17:01:49.712Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":500,"express":false,"returnReason":"not reachable","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff33d7215a2f69817cde3a6","orderid":"252d6g","description":"Pickle","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Masum","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a35d1a92f45097499771","name":"Era","address":"Gulishtan","phone":"43535"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a1f71a92f4509749976f","name":"masum","phone":"34534543"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"Nikunju2","productStatus":"return","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T16:08:18.481Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-07T17:15:16.026Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":98,"cost":8000,"express":true,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff2f6c2652cf165286c1997","orderid":"iuc6l6","description":"Mango","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Raju","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a3eb1a92f45097499773","name":"Lahore Shop","address":"Lahore, Dhaka","phone":"453453454"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a14f70d2bd4ee06fe99f","name":"Raj","phone":"34354354"},"weight":3,"expressTime":"at 10pm","receiverAddress":"Mohammadpur, dhaka","productStatus":"in progress","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-04T11:06:42.123Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-04T11:06:42.123Z","__v":0},{"pickup":false,"fee":88,"cost":3000,"express":false,"returnReason":"","paid":false,"assigned":true,"_id":"5ff225ba78249040b81ada0e","orderid":"b2ij9u","description":"Phone Pack edited","receiverPhone":"01913198340","receiverName":"Masum ed","marchent":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe98c05a843743e86a7849f","name":"Mishu Fashion","address":"asdfasdf","phone":"3453454"},"deliveryman":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe9a1f71a92f4509749976f","name":"masum","phone":"34534543"},"weight":1,"expressTime":"","receiverAddress":"Nikunju-2","productStatus":"Cancelled","hub":{"photo":"avatar.jpg","_id":"5fe75679e6f7a62ddaf5b2e9","name":"Admin"},"createdAt":"2021-01-03T20:14:50.431Z","updatedAt":"2021-01-04T10:15:04.842Z","__v":0}]
```

So I need All value if I do not pass any extra filter keyword except Date Range, But If I send filter keyword like Product Status "Delivered" Only Delivered Product will be shown by the given date range, If I send Merchent id then all products belongs to this Merchent will be given, If I send Deliveryman Id then product status and deliveryman filter will be work. Final think my search query will be work depends on my filter query, my filter query might be null. If it is null then this filter should not be work but the rest of filter will work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you provided.

Comment: Done Jhoepken ..